# NX/cypress does not find support file after switch to esbuild

Tags: angular, cypress, esbuild, nomachine-nx

I switched my NX/angular project from webpack to esbuild by setting

```json
"serve": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:dev-server",
      ...
```

...
in the `project.json` of the NX package.

After that the corresponding -e2e package failed to run with the following output:

```
...
chunk-JTPYGZ63.js   | profile-routes       |  82.50 kB |                12.77 kB
...and 132 more lazy chunks files. Use "--verbose" to show all the files.


  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
  ➜  press h + enter to show help

Running:  xyz.cy.ts                                                        (2 of 43)

Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:

  > src/support/e2e.{js,ts}

The error was:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/...-e2e/src/support/e2e.{js,ts}' in...
```

but the file `/Users/...-e2e/src/support/e2e.ts` exists

My `cypress.config.ts` looks like this

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { nxE2EPreset } from '@nx/cypress/plugins/cypress-preset';

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      ...

      return {
        ...nxE2EPreset(__filename),
        // supportFile: 'src/support/e2e.ts', IF THIS IS UNCOMMENTED IT WORKS
      };
    },
  }
});
```

So if I overwrite the `supportFile` and change the `{js,ts}` syntax to `.ts` it works.

What am I doing wrong. There seems to be something with the `nxE2EPreset` I am missing to work with esbuild.